# What is the intended IBU of Wry Smile IPA?

Tags: ibu, rye

Various recipes have different IBU's, OG and FG.

The [Northern Brewer recipe](http://www.northernbrewer.com/documentation/allgrain/AG-DennysRyePA.pdf) has .25lb more pale malt and .25lb less rye and crystal malt than the [HomeBrewers Association recipe](http://wiki.homebrewersassociation.org/Wry-Smile-Rye-IPA).

What is the intended IBU, OG and FG of this recipe?

Why is the Northern Brewer recipe different than the one listed on the Homebrewers Association website?

Answer (score 3):

OG should be 1.073, 75 IBU, FG somewhere around 1.013.  Maybe NB uses a different efficiency to calculate things.  I gave them my numbers.

Comment: Thanks Denny.  Any idea why they reduced the amount of rye and crystal?

Comment: No idea whatsoever.  And no control over it, either!

Comment: You can't get better than an answer from the recipe's creator!